# My textbox message is not being uploaded into database?

Tags: java, mysql, database, jsp, servlets

I'm creating a box in which i post `job title` as well as `job description`, it will upload into database, but i don't know where i'm going wrong.....

As i submit it says:

```
HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page /submit_job_forum.jsp at line 11
```

Here is my `forum.jsp`

```
<div id="forum2">
        <h1 style="text-align: center;">Want to post on going walking,<br>Post your job description here.</h1>
        <form id="forum2_form" method="post" action="submit_job_forum.jsp">
            <p>
            <label>Job title:</label>
            <input type="text" class="" placeholder="e.g XXX Referral program for freshers." name="job_title"/>
            </p>
            <p>
            <label>Description:</label>
            <textarea class="question_ask_style" rows="3" cols="40" placeholder="Type description here.." name="job_description"></textarea>
            </p>

            <div id="submit_btn">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit Question" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Here is my `submit_job_forum.jsp`

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>

<%
    String job_title=request.getParameter("job_title");
    String job_description=request.getParameter("job_description");

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:8888/login", "root", "1234");
    Statement st=con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs;
    rs=st.executeQuery("insert into job_post('id', 'job_title', 'job_description') VALUES (' ', '"+job_title+"', '"+job_description+"')");
    response.sendRedirect("forum.jsp");
%>
```

Here i created this table to database:

```
create table `job_post`(
`id` int(100) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
`job_title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`job_description` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
)ENGINE= InnoDB default charset=latin1;
```

PLEASE HELP :(

Comment: Why are you not using some exception handling in your JSP to check the possible exception?

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with the apostrophe around the column names, you shall use this character **(`)** or just omit it (as long as you are avoiding reserved words).
While for the values, it's just fine.

```
rs=st.executeQuery("insert into job_post(`id`, `job_title`, `job_description`)
    VALUES (' ', '"+job_title+"', '"+job_description+"')");
```